# Get values of one field on the basis of filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Name    Pay Status

Abc                 123     1

Abc                 456 0

Abc                 852 1

I want to get result :

**ABC**,**1431**(Sum Of Pay), **975**(Sum Of Pay on the basis on Status where Status is 1)

```
Select sum(Pay),CASE WHEN Status=1 THEN SUM(Pay)
From Table
Group by Pay,Status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Pay), SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN Pay END)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: em getting result in two rows... but i want to b one Row current result is like as follow:
Col1 col2 
 
975 975
1431 Null

Comment: @MuhammadWaseem paste your results in your question please

Comment: Pasted it furthermore i want this 
ABC | 1431 | 975

Comment: Mine works with the name in the select, please try it again? Unless you have some more code that you didnt include?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Sum` use outside the `case statement` and also remove `pay` and `status` from `group by` instead add `name` which makes sense

```
SELECT Name,
       Sum(Pay),
       Sum(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN Pay END)
FROM   Table
GROUP  BY Name
```

Comment: Ahhh beat me to it! :)

Comment: em getting result in two rows... but i want to b one Row  current result is like as follow:
Col1 col2  
975 975
1431 Null